Optimizing C System Design for Sensor Data Handling (with limited resources)
I am developing a system in C for a device running Yocto Linux on a microprocessor. The system is resource-constrained, so optimization and fault tolerance are crucial. The purpose of this system is to take in a high volume of sensor data over a TCP socket, process it, and save it to a PostgreSQL database.
Current Design:
Data Reception: I use one thread to receive incoming data frames over a TCP Socket. This data is parsed and then inserted into a circular buffer.
Data Processing: Another thread pulls the data out of the circular buffer and writes it to the PostgreSQL database.
Here are some code examples for my design. For the receiving and insertion part.
// Function to receive a complete TCP frame
ssize_t RecvDataFrame(int socket_fd, uint8_t *buffer, size_t buffer_size) {
    ssize_t total_bytes_read = 0;

    // Receive header first
    ReciveHeader:
    while (total_bytes_read < HEADER_SIZE) {
        ssize_t bytes_read = recv(socket_fd, buffer + total_bytes_read, HEADER_SIZE - total_bytes_read, 0);
        if (BytesRead == -1) {
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                goto ReciveHeader;
            } else {
                return -1;  
            }
        } else if (BytesRead == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        total_bytes_read += bytes_read;
    }

    // Calculate the full frame size based on header info
    uint16_t frame_length = (buffer[4] << 8) | buffer[5];
    ssize_t total_frame_size = HEADER_SIZE + frame_length;

    // Ensure the frame fits in the buffer
    if (total_frame_size > buffer_size) return -1;

    // Receive the rest of the frame
    ReciveFrame:
    while (total_bytes_read < total_frame_size) {
        ssize_t bytes_read = recv(socket_fd, buffer + total_bytes_read, total_frame_size - total_bytes_read, 0);
        if (BytesRead == -1) {
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                goto ReciveFrame;
            } else {
                return -1;  
            }
        } else if (BytesRead == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        total_bytes_read += bytes_read;
    }

    return total_bytes_read;
}

// Main function to handle TCP frames
errno Run(comm_protocol_api *Protocol1) {
    Protocol1_ctx *Ctx = Protocol1->Ctx;

    uint8_t Buf[MAX_TCP_FRAME];
    while (true) {
        ssize_t num_bytes = RecvDataFrame(Ctx->SockFd, Buf, sizeof(Buf));

        if (num_bytes > 0) {
            queue_item item;
            CbInsert(Ctx->Cb, Buf, num_bytes);  // Insert data into circular buffer
        } else if (num_bytes == 0) {
            LogDebug("Connection closed by server");
            return SDBE_CONN_CLOSED_SUCS;
        } else {
            ogError("Error during read operation. Closing connection");
            return -SDBE_CONN_CLOSED_ERR;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

// Function to insert data into a circular buffer
ssize_t CbInsert(circular_buffer *cb, void *data, size_t size) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&cb->write_lock);

    // Wait if buffer is full
    while (cb_is_full(cb)) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&cb->not_full, &cb->write_lock);
    }

    // Insert data into buffer with wrap-around handling
    size_t first_chunk = min(size, cb->data_size - cb->head);
    memcpy(cb->data + cb->head, data, first_chunk);

    size_t second_chunk = size - first_chunk;
    if (second_chunk > 0) {
        memcpy(cb->data, data + first_chunk, second_chunk);
    }

    // Update buffer head and count
    cb->head = (cb->head + size) % cb->data_size;
    cb->count += size;

    // Signal buffer is not empty and release lock
    pthread_cond_signal(&cb->not_empty);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cb->write_lock);

    return size;
}

Questions:
1. Design Viability: Is this a solid system architecture for handling high-throughput sensor data on a resource-limited device, or should I consider something else?
2. Potential Bottlenecks: I am concerned that buffering the data from the TCP socket to an intermediate buffer before inserting it into the circular buffer might become a bottleneck.I might also just be dumb and it might not be a big deal. But would it be more efficient to stream the data directly into the circular buffer? Are there any techniques to manage high-throughput data in a fault-tolerant way without overwhelming the circular buffer? What are some other potential bottlenecks?
3. Optimizations: What other optimizations strategies would be recommended, given the constraints? Is there anything we should specifically watch out for with this system design?
Any advice on these aspects or potential pitfalls to consider would be greatly appreciated!
I have tried researching parts of the system individually, but its hard to find resources regarding a whole system design like this.

Might be more suitable for Code Review SE

Note that pointer arithmetic on void * is a GCC/Clang extension. For portability, convert to char * before doing arithmetic.

Before you post at [codereview.se], be sure to read A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users, as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code is for, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

This question is thoughtful, well presented, and generally on topic, but it nevertheless is not the kind of question we answer here.  It is too broadly scoped and too open-ended.

Thx, i will publish it on Code Review SE

You have not provided nor estimated any data rates for receiving "data over a TCP socket" or writing "to the PostgreSQL database" nor processor capabilities. How do you expect to determine any "potential bottlenecks" or if this whole scheme is even practical?
